# calling postgres function with UDT parameter from java giving SQL is not yet implemented exception

Tags: postgresql-9.3, java-stored-procedures

I am using postgres9.4 EDB for function with UDT (user defined type) giving Is Not Yet Implemented exception.
I am using postgres driver postgresql-9.4-1203.jdbc41.jar for JDBC.
Also is above jar support UDT feature ? Is this implementation is partial ?

Please help me.

Below is the code,

```
public static void oracleToPosgresUDTCall() {
        System.out.println("@@@ inside oracleToPosgresUDTCall...");
          Connection c = null;
          try {
             Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
             c = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/pgtest", "postgres", "root");
             System.out.println(c.getMetaData().getDriverVersion());


             //you can mad your UDT to pojo here Great !!!
             Map<String, Class<?>> m = c.getTypeMap();
             m.put("typ_address", Address.class);
             m.put("typ_test", AddressTypeTest.class);
             c.setTypeMap(m);

             // Procedure call
             CallableStatement cstmt = c.prepareCall("{call fn_test_t(?,?,?)}");

             cstmt.setString(1, "791000252423");

             cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY);
             cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.ARRAY);


                boolean b = cstmt.execute();

             Array arr = cstmt.getArray(1); //output array starts from index 1

             System.out.println("arr:" + arr.getBaseTypeName());
             Object obj = arr.getArray();

             System.out.println("Address obj:" + obj);
             Address[] a = (Address[])obj;
             System.out.println("Address obj:" + a[0].getAdd1());
             System.out.println("Address obj:" + a[0].getTypeTest().getT1());

             System.out.println("=======================================================");
             //MORE

             List<Address> list = Arrays.asList(a);

             for(Address aa: list){
                 System.out.println(aa.getAdd1());
                 System.out.println(aa.getAdd2());
                 System.out.println("t1:" + aa.getTypeTest().getT1());
             }



             cstmt.close();

          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
             System.exit(0);
          }
          System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres offical driver version does not support most of the JDBC conformance.

Non official driver link,

[pgjdbc-ng](http://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/)

[PGJDBC-NG 0.5 API](http://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/apidocs/0.5/index.html)